# Overloading operator< containing class object

Tags: c++, class, sorting, operator-overloading

Having trouble with overloading `operator<`. I am trying to overload the `operator<` so that I can sort my `Line2D` object based on `pt1`'s `x`. But I am having trouble figuring out how to declare the function.

I am getting the error:

`object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Point2D::getX"`.

What I have tried: removing `const`, putting `Point2D &l2dobj` instead.

```
class Line2D
{
private:
   Point2D pt1;
   Point2D pt2;

public:
   bool operator<( const Line2D &l2dobj)
   {
       return (pt1.getX() < l2dobj.pt1.getX());
   }
}


class Point2D
{
protected:
   int x;
   int y;
public:
   int getX();
   int getY();
}
```

Comment: For the future, just throw the error message you get at a websearch engine. Also, extract a [mcve] from your code and post that along with the full error message here, if the first step didn't give you enough insights to fix the error yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Point2D::getX* doesn't accept *const* instance, you cannot apply it on *l2dobj* while it is a *const reference*, change *getX* (and a priori *getY*) to :

```
class Point2D
{
protected:
   int x;
   int y;
public:
   int getX() const;
   int getY() const;
};
```

As a general way declare the methods *const* the more you can, and same for their parameters

Comment: note: `Line2D::operator<(const Line2D&)` also should be `const`. Otherwise, standard algrithms will reject that opereator.

Comment: @Fureeish putting the two operand as operator, `bool operator< (const X& lhs, const X& rhs)` to respect the canonical form

Comment: @Fureeish Thanks didn't know that.